# Postgres JDBC client getting stuck at reading from socket

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, postgis, hikaricp

I have a PostGIS database and a client built on top of HikariCP to read the data from a database. My client can read the data without any problem **on some machines**. However, on some other machines client gets stuck and is not able to read any data throwing socket timeout exceptions.

```
MyClass:120 - Failed to execute HikariProxyPreparedStatement@2091541230 wrapping <my-query>.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:332)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:155)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:118)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    ...
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:140)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:109)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:67)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:293)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1947)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:306)
    ... 32 more

ProxyConnection:161 - HikariPool-1 - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@1aafd32f marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(0)
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:332)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:155)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:118)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    ...
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:140)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:109)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:67)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:293)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1947)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:306)
    ... 31 more
```

Before client throws `SocketTimeoutException` on the database side, I monitored `pg_stat_activity` table. The corresponding row for the query above had `wait_event_type=Client` and `wait_event=ClientWrite`. In addition, database server logged messages indicating connection is lost.

```
LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
LOG:  could not send data to client: Connection timed out
FATAL:  connection to client lost
```

Versions

- PostGIS-jdbc: 2.2.1 (postgresql jdbc: 9.4.1208.jre7)
- HikariCP: 3.1.0
- Postgres server: 10.3
- PostGIS server: 2.4.4

If I don't set `socketTimeout` through jdbc connection string, then connection would get stuck forever. Once the connection reaches it's max life time, it would be dropped and connected again. However, it still cannot read the data. When I set `socketTimeout`, then exception would be thrown.

**UPDATE**
If `socketTimeout` is not set, then `pg_stat_activity` table would have a row for the connection with the following values: `state=idle in transaction`, `wait_event_type=Client` and `wait_event=ClientRead`.

My guess is that some sort of network setting is blocking the read from the server on the client side. How can I further debug this and find the root cause?

Comment: A network trace on both ends should help. It looks like both client and server are waiting for the other. Perhaps a firewall drops the response from the PostgreSQL server.

Comment: You may want to try using a newer version of the JDBC driver, 42.2.2 is the latest driver version.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel switched over to 42.2.2, but no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found out that this was caused by the database server's MTU setting. MTU was set to 9000 by default and resulted in packet loss. Changing it to 1500 resolved the issue.